# Is it possible to remove the $ from an environment variable?

Tags: terminal, bash, environment-variables

I'm on Mac and have just created an environment variable inside the .bash_profile directory, it works fine when I run:

```
$variable_name
```

I just want the know why the dollar sign is there and if it is possible to remove it. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $ (dollar sign) is there to reference variables in bash.  You cannot remove it.  Technically, it's called *[variable/parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)*.  Basically the *value* of the variable is "expanded out".

Using variables in bash is pretty straight forward:

- Don't use a "$" when setting a variable
- Use the "$" when referencing/calling a variable

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=Hello
read var2
echo $var1 $var2
exit
```

In the above script, we set `var1` to "Hello" and `var2` to user input (assume "World").  The next command prints out the contents of both variables on a single line:

```
Hello World
```

For more details, it's best to start with a good tutorial:  [BASH Programming - Introduction HOW-TO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html).  Also have a look at the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html#Top)

Tip:

You can enclose the variable in braces - `${variable}`.  This serves to "protect" the variable from characters immediately following the variable name which would (incorrectly) become part of the variable

Example:

```
var1=foo
echo $var1bar
echo ${var1}bar
```

The first echo would produce nothing since the variable `var1bar` doesn't exist where as the second echo would produce the word `foobar` as expected.  Personally, I use braces for all my variables as a matter of style.

Comment: Wow, thank you, great answer! I'll definitely read up some more :)